# Truncating "wrapping" long string outputs with prefix, appends new line at the bottom of each dump of the hold space

Tags: bash, sed, trailing-newline

I'm trying to prefix console outputs, while truncating long string outputs to a maximum of 60 characters. (Preventing long lines from bleeding over and breaking the prefix)

How come...

```bash
esc=$(printf '\033')
sudo apt upgrade 2>&1 >&1 | sed -e "s/.\{0,60\}/${esc}[35m║      &\n/g"
```

...is appending a new (un-prefixed) line below each dump of the hold space? How can I stop this behavior, or at least append a prefix to it?

Output:

```
║      

║      WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with 
║      caution in scripts.

║      

║      Reading package lists...

║      Building dependency tree...

║      Reading state information...

║      Calculating upgrade...

║      0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgrade
║      d.

║
```

Comment: The `\n` is what moves the remaining string to the next line, so I feel like it's a catch-22 here.

Comment: From my understanding... `${esc}[35m║      &\n` adds the purple `║     ` prefix, then the `&` takes the remainder of the string, beyond the `60 characters`, and and prints it out, after the `\n` (even though the `&` comes before the `\n`. Essentially, this was the closest I could get to my desired output, but with this extra new line appearing.

Comment: do you want to *truncate* the long lines or break them into 60-char chunks on separate lines (ie, wrap)?

Comment: Essentially yes, "wrapping" the line around after ~60 characters, and appending a prefix in front of each line. My apologizes, I couldn't think of the correct term "wrap" and went with "truncating".

Comment: Question has been cleaned, and information has been understood. Thank you again for your help and clarifications Ed!

Comment: Truncating and wrapping are 2 quite different things. You currently have 2 answers, one for each concept - a `sed-only` solution that truncates each line (as your original text said you wanted) and a `fold+sed` solution that wraps each line (as the example you provided shows you wanted). For the benefit of others with a similar question in future, please [edit] your question to just clearly tell us and show us the 1 thing you wanted, truncation or wrapping, and then accept the answer that does that thing so we can delete the other answer or at least comment it's for a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the whole line with its first 60 characters.

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\{0,60\}\).*/'"$esc"'[35m║      \1/'
#          ~~         ~~^^                    ~~
#           1          1 2                     3
```

- `1` remembers the first 60 characters,
- `2` matches the rest,
- `3` outputs the remembered part.

Comment: Hey, thanks for clarifying this for me. This seems to work for my example of `sudo apt upgrade` however my real world example is actually running a python script. `$($VENV_DIR/bin/python3 install.py) 2>&1 >&1 | sed -e 's/^\(.\{0,60\}\).*/'"$esc"'[35m║      \1/'`. When I try to prefix the information with your fix, the bash script seems to just freeze (while I presume the python file is running in the background). After which, the bash shell simply outputs a py error (separate issue), but nothing is prefixed at all. Will append further details to my original post.

Comment: @level42: It makes no sense. `$(...)` is command substitution, it expands to the output of the script.

Comment: OMG!!! You're so right! It was left over from when I was experimenting! I feel so stupid now! So sorry about this fuss!

Answer (score 1):

You're replacement string specifically says to add a newline after every 0 to 60 chars so that's what sed is doing and then it's printing a terminating newline at the end of all of it's output as it always does and that's what's causing a blank line to appear. It's easier to see with smaller input and a smaller range:

```
$ echo '1234' | sed 's/.\{0,2\}/<&>\n/g'
<12>
<34>

$
```

```
$ echo '12345' | sed 's/.\{0,2\}/<&>\n/g'
<12>
<34>
<5>

$
```

There's various ways to solve the problem but you seem to be trying to wrap (aka fold) lines rather than truncate them, so try this instead:

```
fold -s -w60 | sed "s/^/${esc}[35m║    /"
```

Here it is using what I think your original output of `sudo apt upgrade 2>&1 >&1` probably looked like as input:

```
$ cat file
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ cat file | fmt -s -w60 | sed "s/^/${esc}[35m║    /"
║    WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use
║    with caution in scripts.
║
║    Reading package lists...
║    Building dependency tree...
║    Reading state information...
║    Calculating upgrade...
║    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not
║    upgraded.
```

Note that `fold` is splitting the input at white space (when it can), whereas your sed command would chop lines mid-word which would create messier output.

Comment: Hi @Ed Morton, I really appreciate your response here, and breaking things down for me. However, I've elaborated on my initial question providing some further details. Essentially, your solution works for `apt upgrade`, but not when I'm executing a python script. I'm assuming that python output is something outside of `STDOUT` or `STDERR`?

Comment: Seems highly unlikely but you'd have to investigate your python script to figure that out. If you can't figure it out then ask a new question about THAT after accepting an answer to THIS question that you asked.

Comment: choroba corrected me in a comment below his answer, and pointed out that everything I wrote in my edit, was for not. I'm ashamed and embarrassed that it came to this. I'm just a fool and going cross eyed from looking at this script for the last 2 weeks. Thanks again for your assistance Ed Morton. I will cleanup my original question shortly.

Comment: For what it's worth, your `fold` solution seems to work equally as well, however it seems to stream to the console a fair bit slower, and in sizeable chunks, vs the standard `sed` solution.

Comment: The sed solution doesn't actually work though, right? The one in the accepted answer will truncate each line, not wrap it as you want. Even if you got a sed solution that wrapped instead of truncated and the fold solution did end up being slightly slower -  unless you write a very complicated and probably non-portable and slow sed script (I wouldn't even consider attempting it) the `fold` solution works much better by finding spaces to split at rather than just cutting lines mid-word. `fold` may run faster if you remove that `-s` option so it doesn't have to do that work if you don't want it.